# Connection refused only locally. Access from outside works

Tags: networking, sshd, lighttpd

I have raspberry pi with raspbian. Lighttpd and sshd worked fine, but a few days ago
they started to refuse connections from local network

PuTTY and Chrome connection to local IP gets refused. However connection to external IP works just fine

iptables, hosts.allow and hosts.deny are empty-
Using default lighttpd and openssh-server config

Comment: Are you accessing via the ip address or domain name?

Comment: Externally using domain, locally using hostname

Comment: I feel so dumb right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cause of this problem was just that IP changed and hosts file on PC was pointing to nonexistent IP.

Router's open ports are automatically changed to match IP assigned by DHCP